# How to use the twitcurl library

Tags: c++, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use the twitcurl library in linux. I used [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/twitcurl/wikis/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary.wiki) as a guide to install the library. But when I try to run the twitterclient.cpp example application that is given, after it asks me if I have a proxy server installed, I get the following errors:

```
twitterClient:: twitCurl::accountVerifyCredGet web response:
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

twitterClient:: twitCurl::followersIdsGet for user [nextbigwhat] web response:
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

NEXT CURSOR: "code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

twitterClient:: twitCurl::followersIdsGet for user [nextbigwhat] web response:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me by pointing out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I'll list the exact steps I used to install the library.

- Cloned [this](https://github.com/swatkat/twitcurl) project.
- In the `libwitcurl` directory and ran the make command. This generated the twitcurl shared library `libtwitcurl.so.1.0`.
- Copied `libtwitcurl.so.1.0` to `/usr/lib/` directory as `libtwitcurl.so`.
- Built the example application using `g++ twitterClient.cpp -ltwitcurl` and ran the application.

Comment: Have you added your own Twitter API keys?

Comment: @TerenceEden, no I haven't.

Comment: That sounds like the reason it can't authenticate you.

Comment: @TerenceEden, I don't understand. Isn't running the `twitterClient.cpp` program as it is, supposed to give an understanding how the library works? I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you meant by adding your own Twitter API keys, could you please explain?

Comment: Did you follow the guide at https://code.google.com/archive/p/twitcurl/wikis/TwitcurlOAuthFlow.wiki ? It explains how to add your own keys.

Comment: @TerenceEden the above `twitterClient`, written by the same guy who wrote the wiki article, implements the steps in the article. And still generates `Invalid or expired token.`.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question to help solve the problem.